# LXDE .desktop files - How to make StartupNotify option working?

Tags: linux, lxde

As stated in the documentation of LXDE, the option StartupNotify=true placed in a .desktop file, should provide some busy mouse cursor (hourglass or similar) in order to indicate that the application is going to start.

But I never was able to make this option work. Every desktop file starts without notification and very often, thinking I didn't click properly (tapping on the touch pad) I am ending with 2..3 instances of the same application started.

Is it possible to fix this problem by some configurations or it's a bug in the LXDE implementation?